# flutter:error facing in console. app is automatically closed?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

After  add flowing dependency to my app shared_preferences,image_picker,uuid,image,path_provider,font_awesome_flutter,async,http: any,cached_network_image,firebase_storage its showing me error in console page ..
my console error is below ....#####################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 9302): FATAL EXCEPTION: TokenRefresher
E/AndroidRuntime( 9302): Process: com.testhhitan.testhhitan, PID: 9302
E/AndroidRuntime( 9302): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field PREFER_HIGHEST_OR_REMOTE_VERSION_NO_FORCE_STAGING of type Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule$VersionPolicy; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule' appears in /data/app/com.testhhitan.testhhitan-1/base.apk:classes2.dex)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9302):    at com.google.android.gms.flags.FlagValueProvider.initialize(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9302):    at com.google.android.gms.flags.FlagRegistry.initialize(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9302):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzx.initialize(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9302):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzt.run(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9302):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9302):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9302):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9302):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
D/GraphicBuffer( 9302): register, handle(0x6fcc25a1c0) (w:720 h:1344 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
V/NativeCrypto( 9302): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 284 native methods...
D/GraphicBuffer( 9302): register, handle(0x6fc953da40) (w:720 h:1344 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
I/ProviderInstaller( 9302): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
I/Process ( 9302): Sending signal. PID: 9302 SIG: 9
```

my pubspec.yaml ####################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################

```
name: testhhitan
description: A new Flutter application.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_storage:
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_auth:
  firebase_core:
  firebase_database:
  flutter_facebook_login:
  cloud_firestore:
  shared_preferences:
  image_picker:
  uuid:
  image:
  path_provider:
  font_awesome_flutter:
  async:
  http: any
  cached_network_image:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

build.gradle code .....

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
subprojects{
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group =='com.android.support'
            && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')){
                details.useVersion "26.0.1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

app build.gradle....

#

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.testhhitan.testhhitan"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
//configurations.all {
//    resolutionStrategy{
//        force "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"
//    }
//}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Menifest is below ...###############################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.testhhitan.testhhitan">

    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="hhitan_test"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Not a solution, but this is currently being discussed over at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730515/flutter-error-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-prefer-highest-or-remote-version-no-fo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter Error: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError PREFER\_HIGHEST\_OR\_REMOTE\_VERSION\_NO\_FORCE\_STAGING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730515/flutter-error-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-prefer-highest-or-remote-version-no-fo)