# FATAL EXCEPTION: TokenRefresher

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

i have getting following error 2 time, i have tried all thing but i have no solution how this error is occured.

FATAL EXCEPTION: TokenRefresher
E/AndroidRuntime(  370): Process: com.deligence.collectivegiving, PID: 370
E/AndroidRuntime(  370): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field PREFER_HIGHEST_OR_REMOTE_VERSION_NO_FORCE_STAGING of type Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule$VersionPolicy; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule' appears in /data/app/com.deligence.collectivegiving-jOzmRflbUyduL_1oLQGcBQ==/base.apk!classes2.dex)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52732554/10269042

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter Error: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError PREFER\_HIGHEST\_OR\_REMOTE\_VERSION\_NO\_FORCE\_STAGING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730515/flutter-error-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-prefer-highest-or-remote-version-no-fo)

Answer (score -1):

I imagine you're using Firebase services by the exception (maybe..). I had the same problem few days ago and resolved updating to these versions (I don't know which service you're using):

- firebase_analytics: 1.0.4
- firebase_auth: 0.6.2+1
- firebase_database: ^1.0.5
- firebase_storage: 1.0.4
- firebase: ^5.0.2

Hope it helps.